# UWP alternative for WPF's IsKeyboardFocusWithin property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, focus

Is there a UWP alternative for WPF's [IsKeyboardFocusWithin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin?view=netframework-4.7.2) property?  If not, how would you go about getting whether the focus is within itself.

I would prefer not manually walking down the Visual Tree checking each element if it is focused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FocusManager.GetFocusedElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager.getfocusedelement) will ID the focused element. You can then walk up the Visual Tree with [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getparent) to see if it's a child of the control you're interested in. Walking up will be much lighter weight than checking the entire tree child-node-by-node.

Something like:

```
    bool IsKeyboardFocusWithin(UIElement element)
    {
        UIElement focused = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as UIElement;

        while (focused != null)
        {
            if (focused == element)
            {
                return true;
            }
            focused = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(focused) as UIElement;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Also if you use FrameworkElement instead of UIElement it has its own 'Parent' property so don't even need VisualTreeHelper.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the VisualTreeHelper is more performant.